# Figure out why vertices are clipped

Tags: directx11, hlsl, vertex

I am trying to figure out why, at sharp cutoffs in geometry, some vertices seems to be culled for some reason.

I have a heightmap for demonstrating it like this

[image]

And this is the result I get

[image]

See the red rectangles where the geometry is just cut and the skybox is shown behind.

I am not quite sure where to start looking where the problem might be.
I know for a fact it's not colliding with the z-near value.
Any non-steep geometry is fine. Any pointers?

**EDIT**: at certain angles, re-orienting the camera ever so slightly changes things, like this

[image]

[image]

Comment: Only a couple of things come to mind.  The winding, which you can test by turning off Back face culling.  The other is the draw call is short, that is your call isnt requesting enough verts to be drawn.  I assume that if you move your camera backwards you are no longer getting the culling issue?

Comment: I have tried disabling culling (D3D11_CULL_NONE) but no difference.
When I re-orient the camera or move the camera they do indeed get drawn.

Comment: What culling routine are you using?  The technique may have edge cases.  By the looks of your picture, the top and bottom of your triangles are not visible on screen.  You can only cull if all vertices reside on one side of a camera plane.   Looking at your update, it looks like your Frustum culling test is the problem, that's if you have one.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Ernie for pointing me in the right direction. It was indeed frustum culling that was the problem.
I am using CDLOD and built a quadtree from the heightmap to cull with. All I needed was to add one pixel extra of "smoothing".

Comment: All good, happy that its sorted.